# output as part of input stream

Tags: java, io

Is there a way to output some text and allow a user to edit and submit as System.in? Obviously System.out.print is not editable...

Eg.

system outputs:

```
Hallo
```

user edits to:

```
Hello
```

system echos:

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly via System, I don't think. You'll need to interface with the user in some way, either via a GUI or a terminal handling library like curses (if such a thing exists for Java).

Comment: I don't have any firsthand experience, but googling for "java console library" does give a few potentially promising hits, such as java-console-api (http://code.google.com/p/java-console-api/).